# Why are no images showing in picture boxes?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I have a main form that's calling a method from a class file. The class file creates an array of images, and the main form displays them in picture boxes. Everything seems to work, except no pictures show up in the boxes. What have I done wrong?

Code from the LoadCards.cs file:

```
public class LoadCards
{
    public static Image[] cards = new Image[52]; // array to hold the card faces
    public static int i = 0; // counter
    public static string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "cards"); // gets list of all images in our "cards" directory

    // load card faces into an array
    public static void GetImages()
    {
        foreach (var item in filenames)
        {
            cards[i] = Image.FromFile(item);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code from the main form:

```
private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cards = LoadCards.cards;

        card1.Image = cards[7];
        card2.Image = cards[22];
        card3.Image = cards[35];
    }
```

Comment: when you debug this what happens? also, what is the value of cards[x] when you debug it

Comment: When the `GetImages` method is called exactly?

Comment: @SimonPrice when I debug, the values are all null. No errors are being reported.

Comment: @AgentFire I'm not sure what you mean. If I do this...
card1.Image = LoadCards.GetImages.cards[0];
... an error comes up and says GetImages is a method and is not valid in the given context.

Comment: ...and what is the contents of `filenames`?  `GetCurrentDirectory` may not be what you hope it to be.  Better to use a specific folder location. Also you are not controlling what order they are used in. **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: @DaveB, you said "GetImages is a method and is not valid in the given context" is your error. This may be caused because your call to this method (`card1.Image = LoadCards.GetImages.cards[0]`) treats GetImages as an object. Try `card1.Image = LoadCards.GetImages().cards[0]` instead. Or, now that I think about it, try calling GetImages() separately, then address cards as a property of LoadCards, like this: `LoadCards.GetImages(); card1.Image = LoadCards.cards[0];`

Comment: @RobJarvis Thank you. What worked for me was calling the GetImages() method separately. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had forgotten to call the `GetImages()` method.

```
private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cards = LoadCards.cards;
        LoadCards.GetImages();

        card1.Image = cards[4];
        card2.Image = cards[22];
        card3.Image = cards[35];
    }
```